# ¿Cómo puedo calcular el área con varios marcadores colocados en el mapa? Android Studio

Tags: android

He realizado varias validaciones y consultas sobre como resolverlo pero no he obtenido lo que necesito. Me pueden ayudar indicando cual es la mejor forma de calcular el área o superficie en el mapa o de un polígono dibujado.

Comment: Ya tienes dibujados los marcadore en tu aplicación.?

Comment: No los marcadores los añado manualmente.

Answer (score 1):

lo que necesitas hacer para calcular el area es la siguiente instrucción:

```
var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(measure.polygon.getPath());
```

por ejemplo:

```
var sevilla = new google.maps.LatLng(37.377222, -5.986944);  
var buenos_aires = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.608333, -58.371944);  
var nueva_york = new google.maps.LatLng(40.715, -74.002);  
var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea([nueva_york, sevilla, buenos_aires]);
```

Puedes encontrar la documentacion en:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#spherical

Comment: Esto es para Google Maps JavaScript  no Android.

Answer (score 1):

Para android es de la siguiente manera:

```
import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;

//...

List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<>();
latLngs.add(new LatLng(51.893728, -8.491865));
latLngs.add(new LatLng(51.893550, -8.492479));
latLngs.add(new LatLng(51.893216, -8.492224));
latLngs.add(new LatLng(51.893404, -8.491598));
Log.i(TAG, "computeArea " + SphericalUtil.computeArea(latLngs));
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Alfredo, estoy utilizando la clase que comentas pero lo que necesito es, al colocar n marcadores sobre el mapa y de estos obtener el área.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que uses "**Google Maps Area Calculator Tool**" (https://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-area-calculator-tool.htm)